# Spring MVC Hibernate Integration Issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement a small login authentication example through Spring MVC and Hibernate to get a better understanding of both. I am struggling to get the configuration right
My `pom.xml` given below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stockfeeder.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>StockFeederMVC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>


</project>
```

My `web.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>StockFeeder</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>StockFeeder</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

`StockFeeder-servlet.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.stockfeeder.mvc.*" />



        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/View/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


     <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
         <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/StockFeedUser.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1522:orcl.168.0.106" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>

         <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
        <bean id="userDAOImpl" class="com.stockfeeder.mvc.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

This is my implementation class

```
package com.stockfeeder.mvc.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.stockfeeder.mvc.model.StockFeedUser;

@Repository("userDAOImpl")
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public boolean validateUser(StockFeedUser user) {
        boolean flag=false;
    user= (StockFeedUser)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(StockFeedUser.class, user.getUsername());
        if(null!=user) {
            flag=true;
        }
        return flag;
    }

}
```

My `controller` class as follows

```
package com.stockfeeder.mvc.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;

import com.stockfeeder.mvc.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import com.stockfeeder.mvc.model.StockFeedUser;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class StockFeederMVCController {

    @Autowired
    UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value="/Login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String validateUser(@ModelAttribute("stockFeedUser") StockFeedUser stockFeedUser) {
        boolean flag = userDAOImpl.validateUser(stockFeedUser);
        String returnString="";
        if(flag) {
            returnString="redirect:/StockFeed";
        }else {
            returnString="redirect:/InvalidEntry";
        }
        return returnString;

    }


}
```

But I am running into following error

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stockFeederMVCController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDAOImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:715)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1077)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4868)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework
```

It's also complaining about dataSource property in hibernate.cfg.xml. Guidance on this will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation is to go with Spring Boot, which will allow you to eliminate all of the unnecessary container and Hibernate configuration and focus on the specific question you want to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing -

```
@Repository("userDAOImpl")
```

with -

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("userDAOImpl")
```

And if you do not have any other repository, simply use this -

```
@Repository
```

Where you Autowired your jdbctemplate? Also try replacing

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

with

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried above recommendation `SEVERE: Context initialization failed No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}`

Comment: updated my response. Try this and share the outcome or console logs. https://www.javaguides.net/2018/11/spring-mvc-5-hibernate-5-jsp-mysql-crud-tutorial.html is worth a look.